# How to simulate database crash in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new into postgresSQL, in my course in "Advance database" we are given a problem to simulate a crash at given location in postgres, is anyone got an idea how to make a crash?

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE actor SET first_name = 'penny' WHERE actor_id = 1;
-- CRASH
COMMIT;
```

I tested divide by zero but it didn't crash and it only shows an error message!
I searched all over the internet but fin nothing about it, anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: A crash is a crash, not a "controlled error". Kill the PostgreSQL process: `kill -KILL <pid>`.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks for the comment, but is there any way to do that in the transaction?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Well... now that I think about it, you can also try overwhelming the server. Give it a little amount of resources (memory, disk), and run a collosally heavy query. It will crash. It's a lot of work do this properly, but I'm sure you can do it.

Comment: @TheImpaler okay, i will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Overloading the server should *NOT* cause a crash. It will of course cause an abort and a rollback. If you manage to arrange to not have enough memory then an allocation could fail, which you could consider to be a crash if you want to, but could happen to any process at any time. What you might be able to do is overcommit enough memory that the Linux out-of-memory killer steps in and kills postgres for you, but again, not technically a crash imho.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a custom function in "C" - that would be able to send the `KILL` signal.

If this doesn't need to be a frequent occurrence though, you can just call [pg_sleep](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY) with a suitable delay and then send the signal manually (as root or the postgres user).

Note that this is not exactly what people generally think about when simulating a database crash. What you generally do there is disconnect the power rather than just kill the postgres process itself. That tests the whole path down through the operating system and checks the data really, truly gets persisted to the disk (or not) cleanly. That is a lot more work though, particularly with any sort of interesting (so complex, expensive, slow to restart) disk system.

Answer (score 3):

A process can commit suicide:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pg_backend_pid());

FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Answer (score 2):

To crash Postgres you can overrun memory by setting it higher than is actually available and then running an intensive query. The OS will come in and terminate the postgres service for trying to consume too much memory.

Try this:

```sql
SET work_mem to '100GB';
select * 
from pg_class a, pg_class b, pg_class c, pg_class d, pg_class e 
order by random();
```